# How to correctly vectorize map function in Tensorflow data pipeline

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to speed up my training task. After doing some research, I found that "vectorize" the map function, and move the `.batch()` ahead is worth a try. The problem is I couldn't manage to do that. No matter how I do it, there are different bugs.

Each unit of input contains:

- `x_img` as `(6, 256, 340)`
- `x_wave` as `(4410,)`
- `y_map` as `(256, 340)`

And since I wrote bytes into `.tfrecords`, I used `tf.io.decode_jpeg()` for decoding.

My current parse function is here:

```
def parse_func(example_proto):

    feature_description = {

       "x_img": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
       "x_wave": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
       "y_map":tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string)
        }
    
    feat = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
    
    x = {}
    x_images = tf.sparse.to_dense(feat["x_img"])
        
    x_img = tf.stack([
        tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[0], channels = 3),
        tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[1], channels = 3),
        tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[2], channels = 3),
        tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[3], channels = 3),
        tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[4], channels = 3),
        tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[5], channels = 3),
    ])

    x["x_img"] = x_img/255

    x_wave = tf.sparse.to_dense(feat['x_wave'])
    x["x_wave"] = x_wave
    
    y_map = tf.sparse.to_dense(feat['y_map'])
    y = tf.io.decode_jpeg(y_map[0], channels = 1)
    y = tf.image.resize(y, (256, 340))
    y = y/255

    return x, y
```

And here's the code for building `.tfrecords`

```
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrcpath) as file_writer:

    for i in range(x_img.shape[0]):

        print("TFRC SHAPE", x_img[i].shape, x_wave[i].shape, y_map[i].shape)
        record_bytes = tf.train.Example(
            features = tf.train.Features(
               feature={
                "x_img": tf.train.Feature( bytes_list = tf.train.BytesList( value= x_img[i])),
                "x_wave": tf.train.Feature( float_list = tf.train.FloatList( value= x_wave[i].flatten().tostring())),
                "y_map": tf.train.Feature( bytes_list = tf.train.BytesList( value= [y_map[i]]))

                })).SerializeToString()

        file_writer.write(record_bytes)
```

The shapes are the same as each unit of inputs.

Please share some advices. Thank you.

Comment: how do you build your `tfrecord` files?

Comment: @Lescurel I'll add the code with Edit